# Spring Boot unit testing a Service, manual tests pass but mocked service fails

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, spring-boot, mockito

In order to test my Service logic I have to set up some initial test data in 3 repositories. That bit of the test is working, but then the updates the service is supposed to make never happen in the repositories and the test fails. Hopefully if I show the test followed by the service logic it will be more clear what I'm trying to do.

I think I'm probably missing some annotations to do with mocking the service properly. I think the mocked service is not connected to its mocked repository. I don't know which specific configurations to add.

Here is the code:

**test:**

```
package portal.services;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class TestRunServiceTest {
    @MockBean
    private TestRunService testRunService;
    @Autowired
    private TestRunRepository testRunRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TestCaseRepository testCaseRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TestToolRepository testToolRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TestSuiteRepository testSuiteRepository;

    TestCase testCase = new TestCase();
    TestTool testTool = new TestTool();
    TestSuite testSuite = new TestSuite();
    TestRun testRun = new TestRun();

    @Before 
    public void createTestData(){
        // create the test case
        testCase.setId(1);
        testCase.setName("Agent Charities");
        testCaseRepository.save(testCase);

        // create test tool
        testTool.setId(1);
        testToolRepository.save(testTool);

        //create test suite
        testSuite.setId(1);
        testSuite.setTestCase(testCase);
        testSuite.setTestTool(testTool);
        testSuiteRepository.save(testSuite);

        // create test run
        testRun.setTestSuite(testSuite);
        testRun.setStartDateTime(new Date());
        testRun.setEndDateTime(new Date());
    }

    @Test
    public void aggregateDataCountWhenResultIsPass(){

        // test run result is true with 5 data items
        testRun.setResult(true);
        testRun.setGeneratedDataCount((long)5);
        testRunService.add(testRun);

        // test run result is false with 3 data items
        testRun.setResult(false);
        testRun.setGeneratedDataCount((long)3);
        testRunService.add(testRun);

        // TEST FAILS BECAUSE testRunService did not persist any data
        System.out.println(testRunRepository.count()); //output = 0

        // test tool and test case repositories should show count of 5
        assertEquals((long)5, testCaseRepository.findByid((long)1).getGeneratedDataCount().longValue());
        assertEquals((long)5, testToolRepository.findByid((long)1).getGeneratedDataCount().longValue());
        // test failed with NullPointerException, GeneratedDataCount was not updated by testRunService
    }

}
```

**service:**

```
public interface TestRunService {
    Iterable<TestRun> listAllTestRuns();
    TestRun getTestRunById(Integer id);
    ResponseEntity<?> add(@RequestBody TestRun input);
}


@Service
public class TestRunServiceImpl implements TestRunService {

    private TestRunRepository testRunRepository;
    private TestSuiteRepository testSuiteRepository;
    private TestCaseRepository testCaseRepository;
    private TestToolRepository testToolRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setTestRunRepository(TestRunRepository testRunRepository) {
        this.testRunRepository = testRunRepository;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setTestSuiteRepository(TestSuiteRepository testSuiteRepository) {
        this.testSuiteRepository = testSuiteRepository;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setTestCaseRepository(TestCaseRepository testCaseRepository) {
        this.testCaseRepository = testCaseRepository;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setTesttOOLRepository(TestToolRepository testToolRepository) {
        this.testToolRepository = testToolRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<TestRun> listAllTestRuns() {
        return testRunRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public TestRun getTestRunById(Integer id) {
        return testRunRepository.findOne((long)id);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> add(@RequestBody TestRun input) {

        // save te test run
        TestRun result = testRunRepository.save(input);
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                .fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(result.getId()).toUri();

        // update runtime total for test TOOL
        TestSuite suite = testSuiteRepository.findByid(result.getTestSuite().getId());
        TestTool tool = testToolRepository.findByid(suite.getTestTool().getId());
        tool.setTotalRuntime(result.getRuntimeMilliseconds());

        // if the run was a pass, update the generated data count as well
        if (result.getResult() == true){
            tool.setGeneratedDataCount(result.getGeneratedDataCount());
        }
        // save updated test tool information
        testToolRepository.save(tool);

        // update runtime total for test CASE
        TestCase testCase = testCaseRepository.findByid(suite.getTestCase().getId());
        testCase.setTotalRuntime(result.getRuntimeMilliseconds());

        // if the run was a pass, update the generated data count as well
        if (result.getResult() == true){
            testCase.setGeneratedDataCount(result.getGeneratedDataCount());
        }
        // save updated test case information
        testCaseRepository.save(testCase);

        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();        
    }
}
```

The thing is I know the service works through manual testing and inspecting the database, so it's frustrating to me that I can't get the unit test to pass.

Comment: And why should it... You are creating a mock of your service so anything in your implementation is not going to be executed... What do you think `@MockBean` is for?

Comment: Ah ok well I definitely need it to be executed so what do I do instead? I tried @Autowired and the error is `Error creating bean with name 'portal.services.TestRunServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'testRunService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [portal.services.TestRunService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:`

Comment: I do know the answer, but instead of telling someone the answer I like to point them to the resource which contains the answer. A bit like I can give a man a fish or learn them how to catch fish. Bt if you must. Replace `@DataJpaTest` with `@SpringBootTest` (and point it to your application class), replace `@MockBean` with `@Autowired` and if your spring boot configuration is correct (you might need to pass it to `@SpringBootTest(classes=<your-class-here>)`. That will start a full spring boot test. Which is everything which is also explained n the docs I pointed you at.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using the @MockBean annotation for your service.

Can you just try constructing a proper TestRunService object in your setup method and use that?

For example:

```
@Before 
public void createTestData(){
     //set up service
     testRunService = new TestRunServiceImpl();
     //invoke repository setters on your service object
     //data creation     
}
```

Comment: Thanks, When I try the error I get is `Cannot instantiate the type TestRunService` - I removed the @MockBean annotation.

Comment: testRunService = new TestRunServiceImpl();

Comment: That won't work as you will not have a transactional proxy.

Comment: Yes, it is throwing an error `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at portal.services.TestRunServiceImpl.add(TestRunServiceImpl.java:58)
 at portal.services.TestRunServiceTest.aggregateDataCountWhenResultIsPass(TestRunServiceTest.java:74)`

Line 58 of the implementation is where it tries to access its repository for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `SpringRunner.class` instead of using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class`, and change `@MockBean` to `@Autowired`. `@DataJpaTest` is required.
2. If there are some required configurations such as `ContextConfiguation`, `PersistenceConfig` you need to import it using `@Import({ContextConfiguation.class,...})`
3. Create mock bean using `@TestConfiguration`

   @TestConfiguration
   static class TestRunServiceImplTextContextConfig {
       @Bean
       public TestRunService testRunService() {
           return new TestRunServiceImpl();
       }
   }

I tested with Spring Boot 2.1.1.